# Cannot solve this error. Kotlin -Firebase

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I need to get those data to a recyclerview, so I created an adapter class and items class. There's no issues. but this is the error I got:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.busconductor/com.example.busconductor.busCodesActivity}: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property reference has not been initialized

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmIlX.png)

I did all right, but cannot solve this.

[image: Data Class]

[image: This's firebase node]

This's the code

```
class busCodesActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var reference : FirebaseDatabase1

    private lateinit var codeRecyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var codeArrayList: ArrayList<CityCodes>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bus_codes)


        codeRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        codeRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        codeRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        codeArrayList = arrayListOf<CityCodes>()
        getCodeDetails()

        val Button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button5)
        Button.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this@busCodesActivity, conductorMenu::class.java))}
    }

    private fun getCodeDetails() {
        val ref = reference.getReference("CityCodes")

        ref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()){
                    for (routeSnapshot in snapshot.children){
                        val code = routeSnapshot.getValue(CityCodes::class.java)
                        codeArrayList.add(code!!)
                    }
                    codeRecyclerView.adapter = CityAdapter(codeArrayList)
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }


        })
    }
}
```

Please help me. I'm new to kotlin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. Actually It wasn't in code. In my project I has Two app modules. So I have to add both two apps in Firebase. So that's the problem. Otherwise my code is correct.

> make sure to connect all app modules to the Firebase, Before You trying to work with Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you never initialize `reference` that you declared here:

```
private lateinit var reference : FirebaseDatabase1
```

*The `1` in `FirebaseDatabase1` is unexpected, but I'm going to assume you know where that comes from. If not, you probably want it to be `FirebaseDatabase` without the `1`.*

My guess is that you want to initialize that in `onCreate` to point to the database:

```
reference = Firebase.database
```

Comment: I did that. but I got again this error `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.busconductor/com.example.busconductor.busCodesActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.busconductor. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first` Actually, in my project has two app module this's the second app module. first one is work well.